# When i save the typescript code in VS code it takes around 10-15 minutes to compile and build successfully

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, typescript2.0, vscode-tasks

I tried all the solutions that is given in the internet but still the problem persists.

1. I tried disabling all the extensions.
2. I tried reinstalling it the vs code.
3. I closed all the apps that were running on my laptop and tried to compile.
4. I reported this bug in GitHub but they closed saying post it in stack overflow.

This is the link to the [issue that I have raised in GitHub vscode community](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109738).

### Steps to reproduce

I'm using Windows 7 machine.

When I do make some changes to my code and hit save it takes 15 minutes of time to compile successfully.

Below are the images of running extensions on my machine in vs code and their startup activation time.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: How long does it take when you run this from the commandline? How many sources are we talking about? What's your project.json like? What's your tsconfig like? Are you running any linters? Are you doing any opimization like webpack? There are too many options that can cause delays. And please upgrade to Windows 10, 7 is old, unsupported and will become more and more insucure.

Comment: It this all a single project? Or is it compiled in chucks?

Comment: We can't see your computer nor his. So it's hard to speculate what's the cause. Check your task manager, anti-virus, or anything else. Try running procmon or procexp (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511) to see who is spending your time and whether it's IO or CPU or memory.

Comment: My remark about Windows 7 wasn't about the performance, but the fact that it's no longer a supported OS, won't get any new security updates and is therefore no longer a safe environment to run on. Let alone download hundreds of 3rd party node modules and let that code have fun on your system. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information

Comment: You could always try reimaging your machine or running on a VM to see if that resolves the issue. Because it seems likely it's something specific to your configuration.

Comment: can you reduce the project to a single file, compile that, then build the project up from there?

Comment: I tried reducing it to a single file but the issue is the same .